# Why was the low quality "Has sphere with 3 equi-spaced holes specific name & how to graph it?" post migrated to Mathematics.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A fresh new user (@simpletonjack) posted the following perverted question to mathematics.se, claiming he did so because a moderator of this site moved it there: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425860/

Which, apparently, was a follow up to an inexplicable highly voted post on this site:

[How do I draw a pair of buttocks?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66538)

Did a moderator migrate, or suggest @simpletonjack post this perverted question over at mathematics.se?

Secondly, why would you "celebrate" this same user's question (see last link above.)  MSE at least closed the new question very quickly,

Edit: I see this site also deleted the question linked above. Glad we agree on that much.

Comment: For anyone with 10K rep on MSE (math.mse), follow this link to see the question for yourselves: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425860/, and note the comment from SimpletonJack: "My question was transferred here from there! I didn't want to change the place. Moderator did!"

Comment: Believe me, you are not alone with your opinion that this QA shouldn't have been so highly upvoted. The question was funny and its graphic content might be the reason for that, but this is not the point. I just don't like that one of our best posts is about plotting a sexy bum.

Comment: I think we generally keep an open mind about the content on this site as long as it was asked in good faith and don't try to impose arbitrary sets of morals on it. I guess the post and the answer had a lot of upvotes because our members were celebrating _original and unplagiarized content_ ;)

Comment: Buttock question is a disgrace for the site, huge failure of moderators. It is not a matter of morals, it is just without taste.

Comment: "Bottom" line (no pun intended) the question I speak of, listed above, has since been deleted.  That's a respectable action.

Comment: I edited your post to correct some falsehoods — this site **never** migrated any post about panties. The title talked about equi-spaced holes on a sphere and the question body talked about homeomorphic surfaces and tetrahedrons... One could perhaps argue about the quality of that (I'm not a judge of the math behind the question), but certainly nothing perverted about it. Your post and comment train on the answers is needlessly confrontational and based on a false premise. Please refrain from unnecessarily smearing the good folks on this site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For complete transparency, Amy, [here is how it looked like before I migrated it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155532?noredirect=1):

> I'd like to have an equation of the surface. What's the name of it? It looks like homeomorphic to axially abridged tetrahedron.

which from just the text is really not suitable for our site, and is more of a math.SE question.

It would then seem that the luckless user made this edit with the mention of undergarments ***after*** I made the migration; I would not have migrated if the text in your post was already there to begin with.

I hope this is a reasonable explanation.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It is a reasonable explanation.  Thank you!

Comment: P.S. Being confrontational doesn't really suit you. :)

Answer (score 15):

I'm glad to see that you found J.M.'s explanation to be reasonable.

Concerning your last paragraph and, in particular:

> I've lost respect for this site, and will likely never refer an MSE
>   user here. Why: Based on the number of upvotes given to this user on
>   his question

As an experienced user on math.se, I'm sure you're aware that the correlation between vote totals and quality is quite loose. That's especially true of very highly voted questions as extreme cases are largely driven by links from social media. In that context, broadly accessible topics with catchy pictures tend to get loads of votes. The [Batman question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real) over on math.se received 400 some votes for similar reasons, as did many other questions on the [highest voted questions page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). Your [own answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268726/are-there-real-life-relations-which-are-symmetric-and-reflexive-but-not-transiti/268732#268732) surely benefited from this very phenomenon.

You can refrain from referring users here if you like, but it seems a little silly to do so based on the vagaries of the voting system. Mathematica.SE remains by far the best forum to discuss the use Mathematica in a context that's independent of Wolfram Research. Your good friend [amzoti](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5074/amzoti) certainly consulted it a number of times when she had questions.

---

For the record, I can see how one might find the "buttocks question" to be interesting and I don't think that it is *necessarilly* "juvenile". Indeed, modeling of real world objects is generally challenging, interesting, applied, and fun. Many of my own answers on this site fall into that category, as do several of my answers over on math.se.

The human form is uniquely important and offers specific challenges, which is exactly why art students have painted and sculpted nudes for centuries. I don't know the intentions of the original asker of that question but, while it might have been juvenile, I don't think one should *assume* so.