# Is buttocks-type question appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion

I thought there are many tools for rendering real-life scenes, but that Mathematica is not the one.

I see there is a [buttocks question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66538/764) - does this really belong here?

What is the next thing? Finding volume of female breasts?

Comment: related - https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2225/9490

Comment: The fact that there are better tools for something does not make the question off topic. The fact that many (me too) do not like this kind of questions, does not make them off topic either. But I do not claim it should/should not be removed, I just want to clarify what is your question here :)

Comment: @Kuba So what do you think: Does that question belong here? It can't be simpler or clearer than that.

Comment: Please do not make me review it again :), better say on which basis do you claim it does not belong here. In current form your question is not so clear.

Comment: This is *a question* to be used as a start of discussion within community. The community should find and voice a collective answer according to its values, that's why we have 'meta'. If I had answered this question, you could have asked me for 'proof' or 'basis'. You can consider that I don't claim anything, that I just bring something to your attention, and it is for you to think. @Kuba

Comment: I am sorry, there is some kind of misunderstanding here. I don't want you to answer I just want you to be more precise/constructive in your doubts about mentioned question.

Comment: @VividD but if you think it is all you have to say, is my first comment a valid answer?

Comment: The [soccer-ball question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118604/3d-graphic-of-soccer-ball) was one of the next things.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The soccer question is perfectly fine IMHO. But I don't connect it with the buttocks one at all.

Comment: @Kuba, I am *bringing a topic to your attention*. Your answer it about *topic*, not about *myself* or *my question*. That's how I view that question/answer dynamics, and if you want to respond, ANY answer of yours is valid, and should not depend on details of my question.

Comment: @Kuba I can also imagine that you have different opinions as a moderator and as a regular member, that would be IMHO understandable.

Comment: @Kuba I certainly do appreciate your interest in the question as you are a moderator, but I would like also to see some opinions of regular members, expressed without limitations and confrontations, that is what counts the most, in my view, since the site is driven by community.

Comment: My opinion can be obviously inferred from the hints in my question, but who am I to judge? So I leave this to community of other, much more active, users and builders of this site. @Kuba

Comment: The soccer ball is a real-life thing, though, which is what this question seems to be about.

Comment: I don't personally like that question. But, I think that if a question brings joy to a large cross-section of the community, then it belongs here, as an exception if nothing else. At worst, it could be considered puerile; however, the question wasn't sexist, objectifying, or discriminatory in any way, so I don't see any legitimate rationale for refusing it, even if I myself would rather learn something about other subjects. There are simply too many questions on this site now for any of us to be concerned with them all. If it'd started a trend for questions about buttocks, that'd be different.

Comment: Please don't take this as a personal comment, but I actually have difficulty understanding what is different between the "draw buttocks" question and "draw a football" without some additional axiom that the human body is inherently shameful. We've discussed previously the general class of "how to draw *x*" questions, and as a community (if I recall rightly) we agreed that they should remain a small part of the site.

Comment: My opinion is that **the bottocks question is appropriate for the site**, even if distasteful for some. It does ask about  solving a *Mathematica* problem and does not constitute abuse, spam or illegality. What I find it's not appropriate for the site are the attempt to impose a moral directives into the moderators that are not based on technical or legal grounds, but personal taste or religious perspectives. What in my opinion is distasteful  is to imply that there is anything perverse with the human figure.

Comment: Drawing buttocks using algorithms very likely fall prey to *gender bias*: Ask yourself what is the prevailing gender of MSE members posing and profiting from this question? (I should assume strongly male) To alleviate this bias one should maybe strive to draw the buttocks of an hermaphrodite? ;-)

Comment: @gwr Sure, I am with you. :) If this question is appropriate, why not ask question about drawing vulva? That would be more challenging from standpoint of shape complexity, also more difficult, since some participants may have not seen it for a while... :)

Answer (score 6):

I personally dislike that question primarily because I believe it's been floated to the top by extra-communal voting.  I find it disturbing that when I tell someone I am a top contributor and/or moderator on Mathematica Stack Exchange that one of first five Q&A's they are likely to see is *that one*.

Nevertheless I strongly object to your assertion, emphasis mine:

> Buttock question is a disgrace for the site, *huge failure of moderators.* It is not a matter of morals, it is just without taste.

It is expressly (my understanding of) my role as a moderator that has stayed my hand in this matter.  Unfettered by these perceived obligations I would have **Locked** the question as soon as I noticed apparent vote irregularities, which would have prevented further voting.

If our core community (not drive-by voters) thinks this question should be Locked it is *their responsibility* to communicate this to the moderators who were elected by them and, as limited only by the moderator agreement with Stack Exchange Inc., act *on their behalf.*

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the buttocks question belongs here.

Answer (score -5):

No, the buttocks question doesn't belong here.